# Test text file for palindromes

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, io, palindrome

I'm trying to take a text file, convert it into a list, then ask the user for a word length. My function is supposed to print all palindromes in the text file. My output is just an empty list. Any pointers?

```
def main():
size = int(input('Enter word size:')
printPal(size)

def readFile():
L = open('scrabble_wordlist.txt', 'r')
words = L.read()
L.close()
while ' ' in words:
    words.remove(' ')
wordlist = words.split()
return(wordlist)

def printPal(size):
L = readFile()
results = []
for word in L:
    if isPal(word) and len(word) == size:
        results.append(word)
return(results)

def isPal(word):
return word == reversed(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
size = int(input('Enter word size:')) # Use raw_input('..' ) on Python 2!!!

pals=[]
with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as f:
    for word in f:
        word=word.strip()                          #remove CR and whitespace
        if len(word)==size and word==word[::-1]:   #str[::-1] reverses a string
            pals.append(word)                      # save the palidrome

print(pals)
```

Which you can reduce to a single line if you wish:

```
print([word for word in (line.strip() for line in open(file_name, 'r')) 
               if len(word)==size and word==word[::-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning a string into a list of characters doesn't use `split()`  Instead:

```
wordlist = list(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think your output is an empty list? You're ignoring the output of `printPal` by not saving it (or printing it or whatever). Try changing `main` to

```
def main():
  size = int(input('Enter word size:'))
  results = printPal(size)
  print results
```

And make sure you post accurate code in the future. You were missing a closing parenthesis on one of the above lines and you don't have a call to `main`.